# Classifying the connected covering spaces of $S^1 \lor \mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

> How do we classify the (path)connected covering spaces of $S^1 \lor \mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}^2$?

Of course, we start by classifying the subgroups of $\pi_1(S^1 \lor \mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}^2) = \mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}_2$. However, I do not know how to. In this question: [Covering spaces of $S^1\vee \Bbb RP^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2481117/covering-spaces-of-s1-vee-bbb-rp2), the OP asks for the covering spaces corresponding to certain subgroups of $\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}_2$, but are those all subgroups of $\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}_2 = \langle a, b \ \mid \ b^2 = 1 \rangle$?

I think there are more subgroups, at least the ones of the form $\langle a^k \rangle$ and $\langle (ab)^k \rangle$ for an integer $k$, but are those all of the subgroups? And how would the covering spaces corresponding to these subgroups look like?

Comment: It might be more tractable to write the group as the semidirect product $\langle a,bab\rangle\rtimes\langle b\rangle$, where the first factor is a normal subgroup of index $2$ which is free of rank $2$, and the second factor is a subgroup of order $2$.

Comment: I don't think I know how to continue from that point onward thought...

Comment: Where is this question from? Can you provide a source or motivation? There are an enormous amount of isomorphism classes of subgroups (see the Kurosh subgroup theorem), all looking like (free group) $\ast$ (copies of $\mathbb{Z}_2$). And for covering spaces, you need to classify these up to conjugation, which is finer than isomorphism type. I can't really imagine a "complete" answer here.

Comment: Well, in Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology", in the section about covering spaces, there is an exercise in which we need to classify the connected covering spaces of $\mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}^2 \lor \mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}^2$. I thought about extending this to $\mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}^m \lor \mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}^n$ for general $m$ and $n$. There is no difference when $n,m > 1$, but when $n = 1$ and $m > 1$, we get the question I asked.

Comment: Yes the case in Hatcher is much easier since the fundamental group is just the infinite dihedral group (so virtually cyclic). Your group is virtually free, so things are much harder (and I'm guessing undoable).